# Error in inserting data into xammp mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xampp, bootstrap-modal

I have created a form in bootstrap modal. I have to enter data into mysql database. i have installed xammp server. I have created a table name table1. My code is as follows

```
function adddata() { 

    $("#areadetail").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var year = $("#year-input").val();
        var area = $("#area-input").val();
        var plntd = $("#planted-input").val();
        var ttl = $("#total-input").val();


        var dataForm = 'Year=' + year + '&area=' + area + '&planted=' + plntd + '&total=' + ttl;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert.php',
            data: dataForm,
            success: function(html){
                if(html == "success"){
                    $('#table1').dataTable().reload();
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
                }
            }
        });
    })
}


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <form id = "areadetail" method="post">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Area details Data Entry Form</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- ? -->

  <label for="year-input">Year</label>

    <input class="form-control" type="month" name = "year" value="" id="year-input" style = "width:200px ">


  <label for="area-input" >Area</label>

    <input class="form-control" type="number" name = "area" value="" id="area-input" style = "width:200px ">


  <label for="planted-input" >Planted</label>

    <input class="form-control" type="number" name = "planted" value="" id="planted-input" style = "width:200px ">


  <label for="total-input" >Total</label>

    <input class="form-control" type="number" name = "total" value="" id="total-input" style = "width:200px ">

</div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id = "sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled" onclick = adddata();>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

and my php file is

```
 <?php
include("connection.php");

$Year    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$Area   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['area']);
$Planted    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['planted']);
$Total = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);
$query   = "INSERT into table1 (year,area,planted,total) VALUES('" . $Year . "','" . $Area . "','" . $Planted . "','" . $Total . "')";



if(mysqli_query($query)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

i put my folder into xammp's folder htdocs. but when i click submit button it gives me error

> jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/......./insert.php:
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: seems 404 error. Check `insert.php` is in the same directory, where this AJAX is running

Comment: Are you running a web server? The error message indicates that you are not.

Comment: I believe you have not started xampp yet

Comment: What is insert.php? Are you calling it using `http://localhost/something`? Otherwise it would not get loaded through `file://`

Comment: yes it is in the same folder. i have installed xammp.  i do not get ur question @NicoHaase

Comment: How do you call the site where you click the submit button? What is the URL your browser shows?

Comment: i have just created a page and table and put coding in xammp htdocs. and mysql access through xammp

Comment: url is file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/............./index.html

Comment: i have access file through localhost/foldername/index.html, design of the page has disturbed and still got error of inser.php not found.

Comment: can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: when i run my code using http://localhost/Dashboard/index.html it gives me error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) index.html/favicon.ico

Comment: index.html:64 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.html:64)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ index.html:64
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/Dashboard/insert.php 404 (Not Found)

Comment: why i am getting this error